# How can I add an Items-like property to my User Control?

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface, user-controls, properties

It's pretty straightforward to add simple properties to a User Control that will appear in the desired categories in the Windows Forms designer, e.g.:

```
[Category("Appearance")]
public Color BackColor {
    get { return _textBox.BackColor; }
    set { _textBox.BackColor = value; }
}
```

What if I want to expose a more complex property, such as a collection of items of a type I define? I'm thinking something along the lines of the `ListView.Items` property, or the `DataGridView.Columns` property -- where the user of the control can access this complex property via a more specialized pop-up form (as opposed to a simple TextBox or ComboBox).

Even a simple nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nudge is [UITypeEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx), it allows you to create a custom editor for any kind of property, including collections.  Many examples in the framework, keep Reflector handy.

Comment: Thanks, just happened to stumble across this about the same time you posted this answer! Checking it out now...